# Order Object key in select Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with ordering my object key in reactjs.
I would create a select from object like this from my db:

```
{
  liv_1:value,
  liv_2:value,
  liv_3:value,
  .
  . 
  .
  liv_10:value,
  liv_11:value 
}
```

So I have in my component:

```
var selectLevel = 
        <select ref="level">
            <option value="" disabled>--Select level--</option>
            {
                Object.keys(objectLevel).map(function(el, k) {
                    return <option key={k}
                    value={el}>{el}</option>;
                })
            }
        </select>
```

But my problem is ordering, beacause it reorder my keys like:

```
{
 liv_1:value,
 liv_10:value,
 liv_11:value,
 liv_2:value,
 liv_3:value,
 .
 .
 .
}
```

How can I mantain order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reorder the items using a custom comparator like that:

```
Object.keys(objectLevel)
  .sort((a,b) => +a.split('_')[1] - +b.split('_')[1])
  .map(function(el, k) {
      return <option key={k} value={el}>{el}</option>;
  })
```

Comment: Try to inspect the response of your server, what is the order of your items ?

Comment: With the inspect the elements is in wrong order, but in backend I send data in right order.

Answer (score 1):

Add a call of `sort` before mapping :

```
 Object.keys(objectLevel).sort().map(function(el, k) {
                    return (<option key={k}
                    value={el}>{el}</option>);
                })
```

Comment: Hello thankyou, but it don't work, I believe that the problem is object that return from backend

Comment: By the way, your code can be more elegant : `Object.keys(objectLevel)
            .sort().map((el, k) =>  <option key={k} value={el}>{el}</option>)`

Comment: @LorenzoBerti : wrap the returned elment with `()` .. i update the answer accordingly

Comment: I tried, don't work, but the problem is that if I have keys like string from backend, it auto reorder I don't know why! :(